# reading text data with multiple headings in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to read a text file in matlab that has data stored as follows from multiple tests:

```
x1 x2 y
1 2 5
2 4 7
3 2 1
...
x1 x2 y
5 6 8
2 9 0
3 6 7
...
x1 x2 y
-1 4 3.5
6.4 3.6 3
3 6 7.4
...
```

How would I go about reading this in matlab if I have the column headings repeated multiple times? I tried using importdata but it only read the first heading and the data associated with the first heading.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: One option is using `xlsread`. Matlab is not particularly good at reading mixed text and numbers files with format other than: one line of headers and then numbers.

Comment: xlsread doesn't work for text files. I tried it. Thanks!

Comment: Right, I forgot to mention you need to convert them into .xls files with excel first. Cumbersome...

Comment: Yea unfortunately I can only work with text. I have a lot of these files that need to be batch processed. Can't convert each one to excel by hand!

Comment: Gotcha. See the newer version of my answer, I tried it with your example file and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea, a bit clumsy but working:

Create a temporary array with the rows:

```
fid=fopen('YourFile.txt');
Rows = textscan(fid,'%s', 'delimiter','\n');
fclose(fid);
```

Look for the start of each dataset by detecting the `x` character:

```
DataStarts=strfind(Rows{1,1},'x'); 
DataIdx = find(~cellfun('isempty', DataStarts));
```

Now you can extract the rows using the intervals between the indices in `DataIdx`.

```
Columns= cellfun(@(x) textscan(x,'%f','delimiter','\t','CollectOutput',1), Rows{1,1});
Columns= cellfun(@transpose, Columns, 'UniformOutput', 0);

for j=1:size(DataIdx)-1
        Data{j}=cell2mat(Columns(DataIdx(j)+1:DataIdx(j+1)-1));
end
Data{j+1}=cell2mat(Columns(DataIdx(size(DataIdx))+1:size(Rows{1,1})));
```

The individual data sets are now stored in the cell array `Data`.

```
Data = 

    [3x3 double]    [3x3 double]    [3x3 double]
```